# How do you close open dialogs in a silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dialog, childwindow

I have an automatic-lock functionality in my Silverlight app that needs to lock the screen after a certain period. The problem is that open dialogs remains open even if the app is locked.

How do I close these dialogs programatically?

Answer (score 1):

you should add this like :

```
 dialog.DialogResult = false;
 dialog.Close();
```

Comment: the particular problem here is not the actual closing of the dialog, but to find the reference to the dialog. I need to first find it in the VisualTree from that point closing it works exactly like you described...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code snippet to close open dialogs in my silverlight app.

```
    UIElement ui = App.Current.RootVisual;
    foreach (var popup in VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups())
    {
      if (popup != null)
      {
        System.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow dialog = popup.Child as System.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow;

        if (dialog != null)
        {
          dialog.DialogResult = false;
          dialog.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

This only works in Silverlight 4 or newer.

Comment: Set a `DialogResult` and call `Close` can mark your App as disabled (If close animation). Just use one to prevent this...